# Beautifulsoup Parser Truncating larger json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some json data from a website. I'm using `BeautifulSoup (bs4)` as shown in the code below

```
import re
import csv
import json
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

city = 'Helsinki';

csvFile = csv.writer(open( city + ".csv", "wb+"))
csvFile.writerow(["tempid","latitude", "longitude"])

pageID = 0

locPage = urllib2.urlopen("http://runkeeper.com/user/maxspowers79/route/2481336")
soup = BS(locPage, "lxml").findAll('script',{"src":False})
print soup
pageID += 1
print pageID
for s in soup:
    if 'routePoints' in s.string:
        value = "[{" + s.string.split("}];")[0].split("[{")[1] + "}]"
        #print value
        jsonObj = json.loads(value)
        for x in jsonObj:
            csvFile.writerow([pageID,x["latitude"],x["longitude"]])
```

As an example, this is the runkeeper website with a random city and random route I've tested on. The code works fine for other similar pages but for longer routes like this (larger gps json if you view source in the browser).

The `soup` variable is truncated as you will see from the print command issued. Hence, the json is invalid and I cannot parse it.

I tried using a different parser (html5lib) as well but that was worse. Is there a limit to how big a string the `soup` variable can hold?

Otherwise why would it truncate?

How do I handle this?

Comment: I have tested your code with a dummy runkeeper page containing more than 90 thousand coordinates in the json variable ``routePoints`` and it worked fine, parsed well and all items were saved in the output file.

I guess it is not a BeautifulSoup problem since your code worked fine for me.

Comment: @AniversarioPeru Did you try it with this particular runkeeper page I've posted?

Comment: Yes and had no problems with that particular page. That's why I increased the amount of data to see whether it would fail.

Comment: I also run @Vleseg 's code and got the same output `Helsinki.csv` file (a diff command showed they are identical).

Comment: @AniversarioPeru That is interesting indeed. From what Vleseg has said my original code ran into the same limitation for him. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: I am running Beautiful Soup version 4.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems like - yes - BeautifulSoup has some limitations for tag content.

Consider using dumb and straightforward string manipulaion instead:

```
import re
import csv
import json
import urllib2

city = 'Helsinki';

csvFile = csv.writer(open( city + ".csv", "wb+"))
csvFile.writerow(["tempid","latitude", "longitude"])

pageID = 0

locPage = urllib2.urlopen("http://runkeeper.com/user/maxspowers79/route/2481336")
content = locPage.read()

start_at_s, end_at_s = 'var routePoints = ', 'mapController.initialize'

start_at_p = content.index(start_at_s) + len(start_at_s)
end_at_p = content.index(end_at_s)
raw_json = content[start_at_p:end_at_p].strip().strip(';')

jsonObj = json.loads(raw_json)

pageID += 1
print pageID


for x in jsonObj:
    print x
    csvFile.writerow([pageID,x["latitude"],x["longitude"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try rewriting your code with lxml. It should be more robust than beautifulsoup